# How to find average execution time after joining matrices in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql

Hello I am two `summary` matrices, that contains execution time of process with id

```
action_execution_time_sum 
{id="1",pod="a"}  10ms
{id="2",pod="a"}  20ms
{id="3",pod="a"}  30ms

variable_execution_time_sum 
{id="1", pod=""} 10ms
{id="2", pod=""} 20ms
{id="3", pod=""} 20ms
```

As, this is summary matric `variable_execution_time_count`, `action_execution_time_count` are also available.

I want to, have a total average execution time of these processes with id including variable and action.

Individually, I can calculate it for last [5m] as follow.

```
 rate(action_execution_time_sum[5m])/rate(action_execution_time_count[5m])
 rate(variable_execution_time_sum[5m])/rate(variable_execution_time_count[5m])
```

However, how to achieve total average execution time for a specific process. I tried following promQL as the count will be the same for both matrices, because action and variable are part of single process.

```
(rate(custom_rules_actions_time_sum[5m]) + rate(custom_rules_variables_time_sum[5m]))/ rate(custom_rules_actions_time_count[5m]) > 0
```

Will it be okey to use it ?